# Python simple web crawler error (infinite loop crawling)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I wrote a simple crawler in python. It seems to work fine and find new links, but repeats the finding of the same links and it is not downloading the new web pages found. It seems like it crawls infinitely even after it reaches the set crawling depth limit. I am not getting any errors. It just runs forever. Here is the code and the run. I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7 64bit.

```
import sys
import time
from bs4 import *
import urllib2
import re
from urlparse import urljoin

def crawl(url):
    url = url.strip()
    page_file_name = str(hash(url))
    page_file_name = page_file_name + ".html" 
    fh_page = open(page_file_name, "w")
    fh_urls = open("urls.txt", "a")
    fh_urls.write(url + "\n")
    html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
    html_text = str(soup)
    fh_page.write(url + "\n")
    fh_page.write(page_file_name + "\n")
    fh_page.write(html_text)
    links = []
    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
    rs = []
    for link in links:
    try:
            #r = urllib2.urlparse.urljoin(url, link)
            r = urllib2.urlopen(link)
            r_str = str(r.geturl())
            fh_urls.write(r_str + "\n")
            #a = urllib2.urlopen(r)
            if r.headers['content-type'] == "html" and r.getcode() == 200:
                rs.append(r)
                print "Extracted link:"
        print link
        print "Extracted link final URL:"
        print r
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
            print "There is an error crawling links in this page:"
            print "Error Code:"
            print e.code
    return rs
    fh_page.close()
    fh_urls.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print "Usage: python crawl.py <seed_url> <crawling_depth>"
    print "e.g: python crawl.py https://www.yahoo.com/ 5"
    exit()
    url = sys.argv[1]
    depth = sys.argv[2]
    print "Entered URL:"
    print url
    html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print "Final URL:"
    print html_page.geturl()
    print "*******************"
    url_list = [url, ]
    current_depth = 0
    while current_depth < depth:
        for link in url_list:
            new_links = crawl(link)
            for new_link in new_links:
                if new_link not in url_list:
                    url_list.append(new_link)
            time.sleep(5)
            current_depth += 1
            print current_depth
```

Here is what I got when I ran it:

```
C:\Users\Hussam-Den\Desktop>python test.py https://www.yahoo.com/ 4
Entered URL:
https://www.yahoo.com/
Final URL:
https://www.yahoo.com/
*******************
1
```

And the output file for storing crawled urls is this one:

```
https://www.yahoo.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/horoscope/libra/daily-20170924.html
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/utos/index.htm
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/privacy/adinfo/index.htm
https://www.oath.com/careers/work-at-oath/
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account
https://www.yahoo.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/horoscope/libra/daily-20170924.html
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/utos/index.htm
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/privacy/adinfo/index.htm
https://www.oath.com/careers/work-at-oath/
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account
https://www.yahoo.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/horoscope/libra/daily-20170924.html
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/utos/index.htm
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/privacy/adinfo/index.htm
https://www.oath.com/careers/work-at-oath/
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account
https://www.yahoo.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/horoscope/libra/daily-20170924.html
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/utos/index.htm
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/privacy/adinfo/index.htm
https://www.oath.com/careers/work-at-oath/
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account
https://www.yahoo.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/horoscope/libra/daily-20170924.html
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/utos/index.htm
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/privacy/adinfo/index.htm
https://www.oath.com/careers/work-at-oath/
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account
https://www.yahoo.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/horoscope/libra/daily-20170924.html
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/utos/index.htm
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/privacy/adinfo/index.htm
https://www.oath.com/careers/work-at-oath/
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account
https://www.yahoo.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/horoscope/libra/daily-20170924.html
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/utos/index.htm
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/privacy/adinfo/index.htm
https://www.oath.com/careers/work-at-oath/
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account
https://www.yahoo.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/horoscope/libra/daily-20170924.html
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/utos/index.htm
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/privacy/adinfo/index.htm
https://www.oath.com/careers/work-at-oath/
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account
https://www.yahoo.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/horoscope/libra/daily-20170924.html
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/utos/index.htm
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/privacy/adinfo/index.htm
https://www.oath.com/careers/work-at-oath/
https://www.yahoo.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/horoscope/libra/daily-20170924.html
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/utos/index.htm
https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/privacy/adinfo/index.htm
https://www.oath.com/careers/work-at-oath/
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: This code isn't properly indented.

Comment: So much of indentation errors. Can you fix it and upload for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have an error here: `depth = sys.argv[2]`, `sys` return `str` not `int`. You should write `depth = int(sys.argv[2])`
2. Becouse of 1 point, condition `while current_depth < depth:` always return `True`

Try to fix it by convert `argv[2]` to `int`. I thin error is there

Comment: @hussam-hallak The answer above is correct, I'd recommend looking at python's arparse module that does stuff like for you - you'd define max_depth as in int and it would do what's needed - very useful module.

Comment: Much more important: Switch to Python 3. Among other things it flags `int-str` comparisons as errors, so _this_ problem would have been obvious. And tomorrow you'll be trying to scrape websites with different encodings, and pulling your hair out trying to navigate the Python 2 approach to encodings. Switch today!

Comment: @alexis, yes, Python3 it's a good choice. I don't understand people which start new project on Py2)